# Regex match optional third url parameter

Tags: php, regex, xslt-1.0, symphony-cms

I have following URL structure:

```
http://sitename.com/subdir/category-name/subcategory-name/article
```

Here are some example URLs:

```
http://127.0.0.1/ocko/works/videos/
http://127.0.0.1/ocko/texts/stuff/
http://127.0.0.1/ocko/works/teletubbies/oint/
http://127.0.0.1/ocko/works/teletubbies/oint/
```

Category can either be `works` or `texts` and `article` is optional.

This is my regex:

```
(works|texts)(\/.+)(?:(\/.+))\/
```

Problem is that it only matches last 2 examples, like the third parameter (`article`) is mandatory even though I wrote `(?:(\/.+))` for last part.

I'm trying to rerout stuff behind the scenes to something like :

```
http://127.0.0.1/ocko/category/works/videos/
```

And I'm constructing string like :
    http://127.0.0.1/ocko/category/$1$2$3

Comment: Would it help to simplify? Do `$parts = split("/", $url)` and switch based on the parts.

Comment: @Halcyon Looks like `split` is being replaced by `preg_split`, http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php. There's no regex though so I think `explode` would work.

Comment: @chris85 you're right, `explode` is correct. `split` is for JavaScript :P

Comment: I'm actually using symphony CMS and routing extension so I can't do php splits and such, only regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
 (works|texts)(\/.+?)(\/.+?)?\/
```

https://regex101.com/r/oK1eU7/1